# ASP.Net RadioButton visibility inside a RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

Is there a way to hide radio buttons inside a RadioButtonList control programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the hood, you can access the attributes of the item and assign it a CSS style.

So you should be able to then programmatically assign it by specifying:

```
RadioButtonList.Items(1).CssClass.Add("visibility", "hidden")
```

and get the job done.

Comment: `'CssStyle' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'.` I understand setting visibility, but not sure where the CssStyle property is coming from...

Comment: Ahh, an old typo, it should have been the CssClass property and not CssStyle. I've updated things accordingly.

Comment: `'CssClass' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'.`  Sorry :P

Comment: Correct, but it is part of it's parent WebControl class and should be inherited down. (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) You might need to check your references if you're not seeing it in your intellisense.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you have to apply a style attribute to a listitem:

`RadioButtonList.Items(1).Attributes.Add("style", "display:none")`
- OR -
`RadioButtonList.Items(1).Attributes.Add("style", "visibility:hidden")`

Answer (score 2):

Why not add and remove the radio buttons as needed?

```
RadioButtonList.Items.Add("Item Name" or index);
RadioButtonList.Items.Remove("Item Name" or index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
RadioButtonList.Items.Remove(RadioButtonList.Items.FindByValue("3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean with JavaScript, and if I remember correctly, you've got to dig out the ClientID properties of each <input type="radio" ...> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to hide it through the itemdatabound event onload or do you need it to hide after it loads?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I'd assume (for C#)

```
foreach(ListItem myItem in rbl.Items)
{
if(whatever condition)
myItem.Attributes.Add("visibility","hidden");

}
```

Comment: Sorry @James, visibility is a style not an attribute.

Comment: Yeah agreed. That was way back in the day before i knew CSS really well.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to not visibility inside a RadioButtonList.

Try this code:

```
RadioButtonList.Items(1).CssClass.Add("display", "none");
```

and get the job to no display RadioButtonList in layout.